# Optimizing code for various C/C++ compilers

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor, development-environment, compiler-optimization

For those that develop software for multiple platforms, how do you handle the potential that compilers might do certain things better than other compilers.

Say you develop for OS X, Windows, Linux and you are using Clang/LLVM, VS and GCC.

So if someone compiles your app on OS X and they are using GCC and another person compiles on OS X using the Intel Compilers and you *could* optimized sections of the code for the Intel compilers if the person has them.

Would you just check a Preprocessor directive?

```
#ifdef __GCC_
    // do it this way
#endif

#ifdef __INTEL__
    // do it this way
#endif

#ifdef __GCC_WITH C++_V11_Support__
    // do it this way
#endif

#idfef __WINDOWS_VISUAL_STUDIO
    // do it this way
#endif
```

Or is there a better way?

How does one find a list of what directive a compiler offers for checking compiler version, etc

Comment: 1) Pick a language (C *or* C++). 2) Pick a language version (C++03 *or* C++11). 3) Write clean code for in that language. 4) Trust the compiler. After that, there shouldn't be too many cases left that require manual intervention, and those can go into a handy `arch` directory.

Comment: I do it much like that. But I separate the individual implementations into different files and choose which to include via preprocessor as you have above.

Comment: Use `#ifdef` for features rather than implementations. If possible avoid altogether and, as @KerrekSB suggests, let the build settings determine the code to be chosen, rather than the source files. See [`#ifdef` considered harmful (pdf)](http://www.ethernut.de/pdf/ifdefs.pdf)

Comment: @KerrekSB - What about when you can gain a lot by say C++03 to C++11, example threading which isn't avail in the same manner in C++03. Or The fact Intel has a specific thread-building-blocks they advertise. Wouldn't this be a wise exception?

Comment: @Jason The answer you'll get will vary wildly on who you're talking to. Someone who does no performance or cross-platform work will tell you what Kerrek has just told you. The answer you are looking for is actually Ben Voigt's answer - but in more detail.

Comment: @Jason: I don't quite understand. If you need to target all compilers, then use TBB everywhere. That way you only have one single development process. The C++11 threading isn't magic, it's just convenient.

Comment: @KerrekSB - is that wise though? Shouldn't one not intermingle like this? Meaning using TBB with GCC or in other words creating situations where the person compiling has to really have a deep, complicated toolchain due to using aspects from a variety of sources that dont belong to each other?

Comment: I mean I guess one could link against TBB no matter the rest of the chain. I guess my thought here is when to remain compiler and tool chain generic so it all fits together and when to really intermingle specific pieces

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't choose the implementation based on predefined macros.  Let the build system control it.

This lets you build and compare multiple implementations against each other during unit testing.

Comment: +1 While this doesn't directly answer the question. This is in fact the correct way to approach these things. You give a different name to all the different implementations. Then the build system selects the optimal pattern (in a settings header or something) for a particular target architecture.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, optimization follows the traditional 80/20 or 90/10 rule of "20% of the code takes 80% of the time to run" (and "20% of the code takes 80% of the time to develop"). Substitute 80/20 for 90/10 if you like - it's nearly always somewhere between those two...

So, the first stage of "do we optimize for a particular compiler" is to figure out what parts of your code are slow, and if you can make it any better in a generic way that works on all compilers (e.g. passing const reference rather than a copy of a large object). Once you have exhausted all generic improvements to the code, you may want to look at compiler specific optimizations - but that really requires that you gain enough that it really is worth the extra maintenance of having code that is different between the different compilers.

In general, I would very much avoid the "things are different in different compilers".

Comment: Automated tests comparing the results of different implementations ought to make it a lot less painful though.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, but it still means "implement something several times". Most modern compilers are pretty good at generating similar code for similar source, so it should be very rare that you get any major benefit. I do agree tho', it should be a "build-time choice", not a "#if GCC_VERSION > 420" type deal.

Comment: @mats, do your thought here change if someone is targetting multiple platforms like XBLA, Wii, PS4 along with Desktop OS's and Phones. Am I wrong to think that these platforms are going to benefit greatly by compiler specific improvements. Although I dont currently know what Wii and PS4 are using.

Comment: All depends on how good the compiler is, what the code does and about 100 other things. If you do have big differences in hardware architecture, and want to make use of hardware specific features (e.g. SSE and other SIMD extensions), it tends to be better to write a small library that is compiled for the specific architecture - typically with a standard C implementation as well as a "validate the results" option.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, compilers are written to optimize common code, not something specialized written specific for the compiler. So generally you should just focus on writing clean code, using the fastest algorithms. However some compilers are hintable, for instance gcc, through attributes using these attributes lets the compiler do its job better.

For instance using the noreturn attribute will allow gcc to discard function return code, thereby minimizing code size. I guess a lot of compilers have similar hinting schemes.

One could then do;

```
#ifdef GCC
     #define NO_RETURN __attribute(...)
#else
     #define NO_RETURN
#endif
```

And use NO_RETURN in your code.

Comment: I beg to differ here. Compilers can vary drastically in their ability to optimize code. And if the performance matters, you will find that different ways to write the same code will run at different speeds depending on the compiler - and that the fastest version may not be the same on different compilers.

Comment: Obviously its posible to write code, that a specific compiler likes, however I just think one should primarly focus on writing genericly good code.

Comment: Intrinsics, e.g. SIMD intrinsics, are very different between different compilers.